# Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack

Tags: c#, windows-services

I'm creating a simple window service and when I go to debug I get the error, "Cannot evaluate expression because a native frame is on top of the call stack.". Also, when I build the service in Release and run it just hangs.

```
 static void Main()
    {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService1() };

        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

Thats all that is in the Program.cs file, where it normally gets hung on the ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun) line.

Everything I've been able to find only relates to the expression not being evaluated because the code is optimized or having to deal with asp.net and response.redirect.

Code for the Service.

```
    public TruckRateClearService()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        tmrProcess.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
    {
        base.OnCustomCommand(command);
        if (command == 129)
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        tmrProcess.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void tmrProcess_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmrProcess.Enabled = false;

        try 
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry("Clearing Truck Rates Start" + DateTime.Now.ToString());

            TruckRateClearingAgent.Process();

            eventLog.WriteEntry("Clearing Truck Rates Finished" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }

        tmrProcess.Enabled = true;
    }

    internal void Run()
    {
        tmrProcess_Tick(tmrProcess, null);
    }
```

The Internal Void Run() was added just recent on the suggestion in the comments by Eren Ersönmez. His idea has been very helpful for helping debug my logic until I can figure the rest out.

I was able to get the into the Native call stack and it sits on one location, 76F17094 ret. Now I have no idea what this is but maybe someone else will.

Also, when I start the service and look into attaching it to VS I'm noticing two instances of it. One is the normal .exe and another is a .vshost.exe. When I start other services I only see the .exe file in the Attach to process part of the debugger. Could this be because one is on the v4 Framework ( .vshost .exe service ) and another on the v2 ( single .exe service ) Framework?

I believe I got it working. It seems that the problem lied with the timer I was using. The original timer I was using was a System.Windows.Forms timer. I switched it to System.Timers.Timers and everything started working again. Still cant attach VS to it but I can debug it still by using the Internal Run() method. Thanks for all the help n.n

Answer (score 2):

**The problem**

This notification means that the thread is currently executing unmanaged code, and therefore cannot be used to evaluate the expression.

In some situations, you could wait for the call to return to managed code before evaluating the expression.  Unfortunately, in this situation, that won't happen until you shut down the service.

**An Alternative**

You might consider overriding the [ServiceBase.OnCustomCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.oncustomcommand.aspx) method and putting a breakpoint there so you can evaluate your expression.

```
protected override void OnCustomCommand(int command)
{
   //Debugger.Break()   <- or just put a breakpoint in here.
}
```

You can invoke the custom command as follows:

```
c:\>sc control YourServiceName 129
```

Comment: I put everything and executed the command and it worked. However, when I stepped out of the function it wouldn't let me advance any further. And when I went to Debug->Break All, it was at the same point in which the service was failing. I think I'm doing something incorrect here.

Comment: What kind of failure are you seeing?  A hang or an exception?

Comment: The same as I was getting before "Cannot evaluate expression...". Were the service will just hang on the ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun) part.

Comment: Oh, I thought you just wanted to use the Quick Watch window.  Now it sounds like you want a breakpoint in your application code.  Are your symbols loaded for the assembly you want to debug?  (You can find out in the Output window (ctrl+alt+o))

Comment: Symbols are loaded I just can never get the break point to fire in the Program.cs file.

Comment: Did you set an `Interval` on your timer?

Comment: Currently the timer is set for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that you're trying to directly run a windows service exe. Windows services can only be started via Service Control Manager (SCM). In order to be able to debug in VS, I'd recommend something like this:

```
static void Main()
{
    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        new MyService1().Run();
        Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(new ServiceBase[] { new MyService1() });
    }
}
```

You'd create a `MyService1.Run` method which spawns a new thread that runs the service loop. Also, you'd call the same `Run` method from within the `MyService1.Onstart`.

This scheme runs it as a service when being started by SCM, but treats it like a normal exe when being debugged in VS (or being run directly as an exe outside VS).

Answer (score 0):

The exception you're seeing means that unmanaged code is throwing an exception, so the .NET debugger can't show you the usual useful details.

What are you doing in MyService1() ? Can you post the code inside it?

Also are you trying to debug the service by just starting it from the environment. That might not work.

I usually write something like this:

```
static void Main(params string[] args)
{
   if (args.Length > 0 && args[0] == "/console")
   {
      // Run whatever your service calls here
   }
   else
   {
      ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
      ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new MyService1() };

      ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
  }
}
```

Then in the project properties under the Debug tab enter `/console` as the command line arguments. You should be able to step into the application and debug it. You can only debug a service by installing it first: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I was originally reinstalling the service and attaching VS to it. I look Eren's advice and added that to my code so I've been able to just use the normal debugger. However, I haven't found any unmanaged code yet. Would it be safe to go into the properties for the project and turn "Allow unsafe code" on?

Comment: Try the instructions here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdw0c6sf(v=vs.80).aspx